# bcc32 + nasm obj linking error (Fatal: 'fir.asm': Additional segments need to be defined in a .def file)

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly, nasm

it makes my head cracking and makes me feel very bad

I am trying to use standalone assembly with old borland c++ 5.5 (bcc32)

I chose nasm assembler and wrote some routine in asm - assemble it to obj, 
it links ok and works ok;

it works but I used only .text section in asm.obj, 
when I try to use also .data section i get error when try to link it:

```
    Fatal: 'fir.asm': Additional segments need to be defined in a .def file
```

Can not find the solution. DEF as I know, maybe, are used only for dll's
i do not use dll's only static obj linking, so i do not know IF it is borland linker
question and I should try to write some def file seriously (I do not know how) or 
it is nasm question and I should maybe switch something in the asssembler  and then 
it will link :-/

Comment: Why nasm? Does nasm even produce Borland OMF objects? I would have thought you needed basm.

Comment: Yes, nasm produces OMF objects with option -f obj

Comment: borland tasm is old and do not support sse/avx and i need assembly mainly for hand writing sse routines

Answer (score 0):

Since NASM can produce OMF objects (32 an 16 bit), i would recommend using it. I assume you are not going to write an entire application in assembly language, so after assembling your asm rutines with nasm, make a C wrapper and use the Borland linker. (that is just my advice)

Comment: what wrapper? i use nasm to produce 32 bit omf as i said, and link it with compiler 'bcc32 main.c asm.obj' it works ok if i am not using data section in assembly - if so i got an aggrevieating error mentioned above